# What does "flat hypersurface" mean?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, definition

If $S$ is a flat hypersurface *with boundary* in $\mathbb{R}^n$, what does it mean?

Is it just a simple open domain (found in most PDE contexts)?

Comment: "hypersurface" implies that it is $n-1$ dimensional (so, in particular, it won't be open).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an $n-1$-dimensional submanifold with boundary, whose Gaussian curvature is $0.$ An example is a standard Mobius strip, or the same rectangle of paper glued into a cylinder (this, for $n=3.$)

Comment: Thanks. I am not familiar with curvature much. In $\mathbb{R}^2$, is a flat hypersurface with boundary then say a line segment? In $\mathbb{R}^3$ it is part a segment of a plane?

Comment: @soup Curvature is not define in 1 dimension, so it is just some non-self-intersecting arc.

Comment: One way to get a good intuition is that flat surfaces are those that you can make by bending paper - so for example a cylinder is flat but a sphere is not.

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyCarapetis, that is useful

Answer (score 1):

The flat hypersurface in $E_{n}$ is a hypersurface with at least one of the principle curvatures(curvatures in principle directions) is zero. For example the cylinder is flat one since one of the principle curvatures is zero while the sphere has two none zero principle curvatures.